# Batch file minimize with using coloured text

Tags: batch-file

Can anyone help me with a problem that I am having. 
I have made a number of scripts that I run with calling the main script (Run.sikuli). 
Now I haven't done much with batch files before, but I am trying to make a batch file to execute my scripts.

I have the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Change the colours: Background = Black, Letters = Light Green 
color 0A

REM Start up the test scripts. 
C:\Users\<userName>\Documents\SiKuLi\runIde.cmd -r C:\Users\<userName>\Documents\SiKuLi\Run.sikuli
```

I would like green text is my prompt, so we don't confise it some other prompt. 
I also would like to get this window get minimized when it pops up. 
I now I can use this code for that:

```
start /min
```

And it also works, but then my coloured text is white again because a new command prompt gets opened. 
Does anyone know how to get my prompt minimized while keeping my coloured letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start /min "" cmd /c "color 0a & C:\Users\<userName>\Documents\SiKuLi\runIde.cmd -r C:\Users\<userName>\Documents\SiKuLi\Run.sikuli"
```

Run a `color` command inside the started console.

Comment: I tried that first but it gave me an error, but I didn't use the ". Now it works fine. Thanks.